# Purpose of last 2 while loops in the merge algorithm of merge sort sorting technique

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, merge, mergesort

The code below was taught in my Data Structures and Algorithms class. I am currently reviewing it in preparation for exams. The code, by the lecturer, works well.

```
#include<iostream>
#define size 34
using namespace std;

int i,j,n;
int array[size];

void getvalues(){
    cout<<"how many values ";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"enter values ";
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        cin>>array[i];
    }
}
void display(){
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        cout<<array[i]<<"  ";
    }
}

void merge(int array[], int low, int mid, int high){
    i=low; //low of first half
    j=mid+1; //low of second half 
    int k=low; // LOW for temporary new sorted array that we will form
    int temp[n];
    
    // Its like while low of each list <= high
    while(i<=mid && j<=high){  //?????????????????????????????
        // if array at i < array at j...
        if(array[i] < array[j]){
            temp[k] = array[i]; // set array at k to be equal to array at i
            i++; //move foward by one
            k++; //move foward byone
            
        } 
        else // if array at j < array at i...
        {
            temp[k]=array[j]; // set array at k to be equal to array at j instead
            k++; //move foward by one
            j++; //move foward by one
        }
            
    }
    
    //mop remaining values
    while(i<=mid){
        temp[k]=array[i];
            i++;
            k++;    
    }
    
    while(j<=high){
        temp[k]=array[j];
            k++;
            j++;
    }
    //copy to original array
    for(i=low; i<k; i++)
    array[i]=temp[i];
}

void mergesort(int array[], int low, int high)
{
    int mid;
    if (low < high)
    {
        mid=(low+high)/2;
        // Split the data into two half.
        mergesort(array, low, mid);
        mergesort(array, mid+1, high);
 
        // Merge them to get sorted output.
        merge(array, low, mid, high);
    }
}

 
 int main(){
    getvalues();
    mergesort(array, 0, n-1);
    display();
}
```

However, I do not understand the purpose of the last 2 while loops within the merge (not mergesort) function. I thought just 1 would be enough.

Could someone kindly explain to me why we need 2 extra while loops?

**Help with testing**
I also need help on how to test the result after the first while loop is exited. How can I print that result? I have tried using the display() function amongs other methods that return weird results or simply do not work. May I also get help with that?

Below is the "weird result" I get after trying to use display to print after the first while loop in merge function. It even results in a distortion of the result since the array is not sorted. How can I test-print in c++?

[running the program after test-printing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJYTz.png)

Comment: I see a lot of bad programming habits here. For instance, you've `using namespace std;` and then `cin>>array[i]`. Are you aware c++ have a `std::array` class template? Also I see a lot of global variables in your program. Avoid using global variables wherever possible. I would recommend using a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: The code won't compile. We need a [mcve]

Comment: @user12002570 That is how we have been taught all semester. It is the method I understand best. Starting to learn new ways of approaching the concepts may not be a good idea one week to the exam.Maybe you can advise? Would you be kind enough to work with the code as it is.

Comment: @user12002570 Alright, I'll edit the code as soon as I learn what a minimal reproducible example is. But meanwhile is it possible to run the code on dev c++? or on this online compiler: https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/online-compiler/ The code runs well on both platforms

Comment: *"That is how we have been taught all semester..."* I highly recommend changing the teacher/course etc if possible and using a [better source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: In the general case the two arrays to merge may not be the same length. It seems to me that those last two while loops are to copy the remaining elements of the longer array over to the result. One for if the `i` array is longer, the other for if the `j` array is longer.

Comment: There's a comment that states what they do `mop remaining values`

Comment: @MargretMauno `int temp[n]` -- *That is how we have been taught all semester* -- You were taught to do this?  This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their size denoted by a compile-time constant, not a runtime variable.  This should be `std::vector<int> temp(n);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialization: We have two sorted arrays, A and B, and we're merging them into a single sorted array, C.

The idea of ​​the merge function is:

1.We iterate through both arrays simultaneously using two indexes, one for each array.
While both arrays have elements remaining, we compare the elements at the current index. The smaller element is appended to the combined array, C.
We increase the index of the array from which we took the smaller element and increase the index of array C.

2. if array A reaches its end before B array, we know that the remaining elements in the other array are already sorted. Therefore, we simply copy the remaining elements from that array into C.
   This is done in a separate loop after the main merge loop.(this is the second while loop)
3. The third while loop does the same as 2 but checks the opposite. (if B reaches the end before A ).

hope i helped, good luck in your exam!

Answer (score 0):

Only one of the two loops will be run (the other will loop zero times). This is easier to understand if the code to handle end of run is included in each part of the if | else compare logic in the merge function.

A one time allocation of the second array and one time copy at entry to merge sort and then alternating the direction of merge with each level of recursion eliminates the need for a copy back in `Merge`. The code below is C or C++ code (it uses malloc instead of new), the range of data is [bgn, end) instead of [low, high], where `end` is 1+index to the last element, which is more common in the case of merge sort.

```
void Merge(int a[], int bgn, int mid, int end, int b[])
{
int i, j, k;
    i = bgn, j = mid, k = bgn;
    while(1){
        if(a[i] <= a[j]){               // if left smaller
            b[k++] = a[i++];            //  copy left element
            if(i < mid)                 //  if not end of left run
                continue;               //    continue
            do                          //  else copy rest of right run
                b[k++] = a[j++];
            while(j < end);
            break;                      //   and break
        } else {                        // else right smaller
            b[k++] = a[j++];            //  copy right element
            if(j < end)                 //  if not end of right run
                continue;               //    continue
            do                          //  else copy rest of left run
                b[k++] = a[i++];
            while(i < mid);
            break;                      //   and break
        }
    }
}

void MergeSortR(int b[], int bgn, int end, int a[])
{
    if (end - bgn <= 1)                 // if run size == 1
        return;                         //   consider it sorted
    int mid = (end + bgn) / 2;
    MergeSortR(a, bgn, mid, b);
    MergeSortR(a, mid, end, b);
    Merge(b, bgn, mid, end, a);
}

void MergeSort(int a[], int n)          // n = size (not size-1)
{
    if(n < 2)
        return;
    int *b = (int *) malloc(n*sizeof(int)); // 1 time allocate and copy
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        b[i] = a[i];
    MergeSortR(b, 0, n, a);             // sort data from b[] into a[]
    free(b);
}
```

Link to Wikipedia article showing the same logic:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Top-down_implementation

Comment: `int *b = malloc(n*sizeof(int));` -- C++ requires that the return value of `malloc` be casted to the actual pointer type, unless the type that is being assigned to is a `void *`.